# Send a parameter to user control from main form when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have an object called Campaign in my program. I have a `User Control` that will use the properties of this object. 
But at the beginning of my program, this object is set to `null`. It's only when the user clicks a "Next" button that I would like my user control to receive this object.
But in my main form's `InitializeComponent()` method, a new instance of my user control is generated before I want it to. This instance takes no arguments.

```
this.userControlFileCampaign1 = new Postbag.UserControlFileCampaign();
```

So what I want to do is to send this Campaign object to my user control's constructor. But upon changing my constructor, the compiler tells me that:

> 'Postbag.UserControlFileCampaign' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 0 arguments

Having two constructors does not help me because it is always the one with zero arguments that is run.

So how can I send this Campaign object to my user control?

Answer (score 1):

Create an overload of the constructor that takes zero parameters and simply calls the one that does:

```
public UserControlFileCampaign()
    : this(null) { }

public UserControlFileCampaign(Campaign camp)
{
}
```

You will not be able to avoid having the designer's code call a constructor...it must exist to be on the form.  If you want to send the `Campaign` object later, just expose a property or method that you can use to do so at any point post-construction.

Comment: so basically we should use Constructor Chaining right? But when we say ": this(null)" doesn't it run the constructor with no arguments which is itself? shouldn't it refer to the constructor that is supposed to be run like ": this(camp)"? / And by the way, knowing almost all UserControls are initialized at the Main Form's initialization, is this the common way of passing parameters to User Controls?

Comment: Yes, this is chaining.  I don't understand your question.  Form code will call _something_, so this just ensures that the UserControl can be constructed with or without a parameter.  If you do not have a `Campaign` to send at that time, then don't.  Pass it later on via a property or a method.

Comment: my problem is that my user control's constructor is called at the beginning of the program. And its load event is also called before I want it to. I only want my user control to be initialized when that next button is clicked and not before that. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I think you should reconsider how you have designed it then.  Move the code that is happening at construction to a method that can be called when you want it called.  Allow the control to be constructed and exist in a minimalist way, and let further initialization happen as it's needed, instead of trying to do it all up-front.

Comment: As DonBoitnott suggests you might want to use a property instead. If your user control exists the whole time it would not be logic to use the constructor for passing a parameter later on...

Answer (score 0):

Empty your `UserControl's` constructor, and move the code to some other method, like `SetCampaignAndStart()`. Add this new method to your `UserControl`:

```
public void SetCompaignAndStart(Campaign campObject)
{
   // Move constructor code here,
   // where the campaign object is needed
}
```

When the user click `Next`, run this usercontrol's method to "start" it:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myUserControl.SetCompaignAndStart(campaignObject);
}
```